# "key column doesn't exist in table"

Tags: mysql

I'm making a database in MySQL in class and I'm having trouble adding foreign keys to my tables. I already added most of the foreign keys to my tables when I created the tables but obviously I couldn't add all of them in the creation process. I'm trying to add the remaining foreign keys with the below method.

```
ALTER TABLE ORDERS 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (customer_sid) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(SID);
```

For some reason the error message listed in the title keeps popping up. The code is below.  I can see the tables are coming out a bit funny but if you read them from left to right you can see what it says. What do you think?

```
mysql> show columns from games;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| gameID     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| videoGames | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| year       | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| genreID    | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| companyID  | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| directorID | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> show columns from consoles;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| consoleID    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| console      | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| yearReleased | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> alter table games
    -> add foreign key(consoleID) references consoles(consoleID);
ERROR 1072 (42000): Key column 'consoleID' doesn't exist in table
```

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE <table> would be more useful than show columns

Answer (score 1):

There is no field `consoleID` in your table `games`. You need to create it before trying to add a constraint on it. This will add `consoleID` and create the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE games ADD COLUMN consoleID INTEGER NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE games ADD FOREIGN KEY (consoleID) REFERENCES consoles(consoleID);
```

You should think about adding a third table where you associate `consoles` with `games` because some games are multiplateform. :)

Comment: Oh great thanks! haha actually I have that one planned, I just haven't made it yet! Thanks again!